# Class inside class

Tags: java, class, this

```
public class FirstClass
{
    private FirstClass()
    {
        new Thread(new Thread()).start();
    }

    public static void checkSomething(FirstClass clas)
    {
        //doing something
    }
    private class Thread implements Runnable
    {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            checkSomething(????);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new FirstClass();
    }
}
```

my question is, what to write in ???? to get class FirstClass, i cannot write "this", coz i would get Thread.

Comment: Hint: naming your class the same as one in `java.lang` is a **really, really** bad idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write `FirstClass.this` to access the enclosing class instance.

Comment: In fact the OP could use FirstClass.checkSomething() directly as it is static. But I think your answer will fit the need better :)

Comment: :O i didnt know anything like that, thx a lot ^^ i really appreciate that :)

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I think his method `checkSomething` takes a `FirstClass` object in parameter and that's the object he wanted to reach by using `this` in the inner class, in order to be able to pass it as a parameter to the static method.